# Contact.url token is not a hyperlink

Tags: civimail, tokens, mailing

When I send a bulk mailing I use the {contact.url} token, when the email comes through though the url is not a hyperlink.

Is there a way to amend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the token into a hyperlink

Edit: < a href="{contact.url}">{contact.url}< /a >

Surprisingly worked

Comment: Can you edit your answer to share how you did it for the sake of people who come across this post in the future?